# Is it possible to study information theory while studying a first course on probability?

Tags: probability, information-theory

I'm currently taking a course on intro to probability.

The course is not mathematically rigorous and does not invoke theorems from real analysis, etc. The course covers all the way from basic notions permutations, combinations, to pdf, cdf, till just before law of large numbers.

I wonder if I would also learn information theory at the same time. For that, I will need a simple set of notes or (even better) an introductory text that goes from the ground up. I think something just under C.E. Shannon's thesis and above basic notions in probability will help.

Has anyone taken a similar course or been in a similar situation? Any literature recommendation will be helpful.

Comment: it shouldn't necessarily hurt, but I am concerned that the rigor of the course leaves much desired in terms of intuition and understanding required to learn even basic information theory

Comment: Yea, I don't know if you can really understand any text in information theory without the basics down. Basics concepts like expected value won't be introduced until the end of your class. Though you could go along and try to understand the basic philosophies behind the definitions and ideas brought up in the texts, you just won't really be ble to understand the theorems and such that will be in books most likely

Comment: No, you should't. Information theory relies heavily on probability.

Comment: A good, cheap introduction to information theory is the Dover book by Robert Ash. It's only $13 at Amazon, so no harm getting it even if you aren't fully prepared to read it yet. It might be motivating to see how probability is applied, and you can always go back and review/learn probability topics as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend taking both courses simultaneously. Most in the field would consider probability theory a prerequisite and not a co-requisite for information theory.

When it comes to texts, you might take a look at David Applebaum's [Probability and Information: An Integrated Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052172788X). It's one of the very few that treats both subjects together - though still sequentially.  (It also has an elegant and more sophisticated approach to measure theory for probability without getting into the excessive rigor of analysis that is typically presented.)

For probability texts, you're likely better off with those from [Leon-Garcia](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131471228) (the most popular text in many electrical engineering departments) or older inexpensive Dover Publications like those from [Paul Pfeiffer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486636771) or [Alfred Renyi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486458679) which were specifically written (and include information theoretic examples/related material) for students who expected to move into information theory afterwards.